# Get locator value using java webdriver selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get the following selector value:

```
<span title="Error - Unresolved" class>
```

my intention is to get the title value in this case --> "Error - Unresolved" 
Is there a clean, elegant way of doing it? 
I am using the getText() method but it returns me "" and this is correct but I can't find a way to extract the value of the title in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to **locate** the element by HTML `title` attribute you can do it using [XPath](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) selector like:

   ```
   WebElement mySpan = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='Error - Unresolved']"));
   ```
2. If you already have an instance of a [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) and need to have its `title` attribute value - go for [getAttribute()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) function like:

   ```
   String title = mySpan.getAttribute("title")
   ```

   [image]